# How to Update Date in each row with different dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to update date column of the table with dates in the increment of 1 for all rows.

How do I do it in MySQL?

Table: tbl_question_of_the_day

Table Columns:
ID,
Date, Text

So the output that I want is:

| ID | Date | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 26-May-21 | Hello |
| 2 | 27-May-21 | How are you |
| 3 | 28-May-21 | Hello |

Thanks!

Comment: Show table as CREATE TABLE script. Show source data as INSERT INTO. Show desired output as formatted table, with explanations for each separate row. Select **one** DBMS and remove wrong tag.

Comment: @akina, Is this better?

Comment: Better, but not enough nevertheless. CREATE TABLE script would be more useful. Now your data looks like `Date` column has VARCHAR datatype and stores the date in custom format. And you show desired output without source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
update tbl_question_of_the_day set date = current_date + interval ID day
```